# SciFi novel I can't remember the name from

Tags: story-identification, novel, artificial-intelligence

It's about these two sisters whose colony are forced to mine some like psi-ore or something because it messes with robots AI. The younger sister is a genius though (as happens to many of the children of this planet due to psi-ore radiation). She's taken off-planet to be trained because of her high IQ but before she goes she tricks a robot into going into the psi-mine and it becomes self-aware. After that the girl and the robot work together since the self-aware robot would be destroyed if discovered and the genius girl can use him for her own plans.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like Fortune's Rising by Sara King.  Came out last year.  Not very good.